# How to display D-stroke symbol in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I want to display the D-stroke symbol (`\DJ`) using the following code, but I failed. Could anyone tell me how to make it correct?

As shown in the figure, the symbol `$\mu$` works well but the `$\DJ$` symbol doesn't appear.

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated! 
[image]

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use("pgf")
pgf_with_custom_preamble = {
    "text.usetex": True,    # use inline math for ticks
    "pgf.rcfonts": False,   # don't setup fonts from rc parameters
    "pgf.preamble": [
        '\\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}'
        '\\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}'
        '\\usepackage{tgtermes}'
     ]
}
mpl.rcParams.update(pgf_with_custom_preamble)
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('$\mu$')
plt.title('$\DJ$')
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think this is marginally on topic, because it's not specified how the translation to TeX is done.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol `\DJ` belongs to text mode and creates a warning in math mode:

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \DJ invalid in math mode ...
```

Solution is using text mode for the symbol (`\mbox{\DJ}` inside math or `\text{\DJ}` if package `amstext` or `amsmath` is loaded):

```python
...
plt.xlabel(r'$\mu$')
plt.title(r'\DJ')
plt.savefig('test.pdf')
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Dear Heiko, thank you very much! It works now!